# В чем специфика работы prefetch_related?

Tags: django

В `Django` есть две функции `select_related` и `prefetch_related`.

`select_related` - это по сути обычный join по таблице foreign key, а `prefetch_realted` - можно сказать reverse join в отношениях many-to-one и many-to-many.

Прочитал, что

> select_related использует отношения внешнего ключа (foreign key
> relationship), то есть использование соединения в самом запросе, в то
> время как в prefetch_related есть отдельный поиск и соединение на
> стороне python.

Что это значит? Понятно, что `select_related` сделает запрос `join` в базу, но разве `prefetch_related` не будет делать запросов?

В статье еще был приведен фрагмент кода:

````
country = Country.objects.prefetch_related(‘state’).get(id=1)
>> for state in country.state.all():
>> print(state.state_name)
```Query Executed

SELECT id, country_name FROM country WHERE id=1;
SELECT state_id, state_name WHERE State WHERE country_id IN (1);
````

Второй запрос для поиска ведь тоже выполнился, тогда почему говорится, что выполняется на стороне `Python`?

Comment: Думаю, вы просто запудрили себе мозги мутными статьями. select_related делает join, prefetch_related делает отдельный select - вот и всё, а что там "на стороне python" происходит с результатами запросов - не наши проблемы

Comment: @andreymal спасибо!